# How can I get a URL entered into WinForms OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

If a user enters a URL into a Windows Forms OpenFileDialog then the dialog box (on more modern versions) of Windows will download the file and open it from a temporary directory.  Is there any way to get at the entered URL?  Could the new-fangled IFileDialog help?

Please note that I am not looking for the file:// equivalent of a local file. This is for when the user enters the location of something on the Internet  into the file dialog.  e.g. http://example.com/path.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809936/url-as-filename-in-openfileidialog-c-sharp) asks essentially the same question, but didn't get a useful answer, perhaps because he asks that the result appear in the FileName property.

Comment: Can you add source link about "Windows will download the file and open it from a temporary directory"? Looks like behaviour implemented in some app, not OS/framework functionality. Also, have you tried `FileName` property?

Comment: @CodingFeles, it is something I have observed using my own application on a Windows 10 computer, but it doesn't happen on my Windows 7 computer.  The FileName property contains the temporary path, which the file has been downloaded to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL as FileName in OpenFileIDialog C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809936/url-as-filename-in-openfileidialog-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set a windows hook to listen for text changes. This code currently picks up value changes from all fields, so you will need to figure out how to only detect the `ComboBox` filename field.

```
    public class MyForm3 : Form {

        public MyForm3() {
            Button btn = new Button { Text = "Button" };
            Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventProc lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);


        private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
        private const uint EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE = 0x800E;

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            uint pid = 0;
            uint tid = 0; 
            using (var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(p.MainWindowHandle, out pid);

            var hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, CallWinEventProc, pid, tid, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);

            OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();
            d.ShowDialog();
            d.Dispose();
            UnhookWinEvent(hHook);

            MessageBox.Show("Original filename: " + OpenFilenameText);
        }

        private static String OpenFilenameText = "";
        private static WinEventProc CallWinEventProc = new WinEventProc(EventCallback);
        private delegate void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime);
        private static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(256);
            GetClassName(hWnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
            if (sb1.ToString() == "Edit") {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
                OpenFilenameText = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get URL (not download file), set CheckFileExists flag to false.
Example code below

```
        string urlName = null;
        using (var dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.CheckFileExists = false;

            dlg.ShowDialog();
            urlName = dlg.FileName;
            urlName = Path.GetFileName(urlName);

        }
```

Comment: This works in a sense, but it makes the dialog useless for selecting files, which is its main purpose, because it won't do any validation on the file name.